# Surface Table Project with Web Browsers

Tags: webbrowser-control, pixelsense, multi-touch

I'm working on a project that will use a Surface table to show web browsers that can be manipulated via the multitouch behaviors. I'd like to be able to show a browser at full screen and then resize, move, etc.

I'd also like to be able to launch a new, separate browser windows that can also be manipulated through multitouch.

Any suggestions on controls to look into for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a non-trivial task.  As far as I know, many have tried and put months of effort into it but none of been very successful.  Don't even bother trying to get something to work well based on WPF's built in WebBrowser control.  Best bet is to start with the SurfaceScatterView control and trying to put a 'Chromium' control inside of it (http://wpfchromium.codeplex.com/).  It appears that even this isn't straightforward though: http://wpfchromium.codeplex.com/discussions/244117